# blueimp jquery upload delete on linux does not work

Tags: php, jquery, linux, blueimp

I'm developing a website on a windows 7 environment. I use the blueimp jquery upload plugin and it works out of the box. When I upload it to my linux php hosting uploading files works fine, but using the delete button doesn't. I downloaded the newest version of blueimp and uploaded it to my linux php hosting and it wont delete also. I have another hosting account at another hoster and uploading the newest version works also.

Somebody an idea what setting can cause the trouble?

===========================================================================

I installed firebug and I get the following

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>403 Forbidden</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Forbidden</h1>
<p>You don't have permission to access /download/server/php/
on this server.</p>
<p>Additionally, a 404 Not Found
error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.</p>
</body></html>
```

The php/ folder had 755 recursive rights. I also set it to 777 recursive. Still the same error.

Comment: Please check what error you are receiving in firebug or chrome developer tools.I am using it on my linux hosting and it all works fine.Host should not be a problem.Try to add some more details by debugging it.

Comment: I think it is related to the host. On al other hosting providers I tested I get these response headers. I contacted my host and they answered that they don't support cross-site requests

Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:false
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Content-Type, Content-Range, Content-Disposition
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:OPTIONS, HEAD, GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*

Why is this only when I delete a file?

Comment: If access-control allow origin is the issue it should also give you error for uploads!Do you upload to the same server or some other location?

Answer (score 1):

I've just problem too, a have something change it for work and it run. May be it help you

1. First at font end need change method for button delete
   Find and replce  data-type="POST"
2. Open file server/php/UploadHandle.php

Change this code

```
case 'POST':
  $this->post($this->options['print_response']);
break;
```

To

```
case 'POST':
  if ($_REQUEST['file']!='')
  {
    $this->delete($this->options['print_response']);
  } else {
    $this->post($this->options['print_response']);
  }
break;
```